# Mac [Sierra] recover Bootcamp [Windows 10] through VHD

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, boot-camp, windows-7-restore

Recently using Windows' built in restore from image is failing for me when restoring from a recent image I have.  Which leaves in a bit of a sticky situation where I can't boot into Bootcamp [windows] anymore.  Fortunately the Windows image backup creates vhd files which allows me to get to the data.  However, what I'm hoping to be able to do is take all the contents of the vhd and restore it on Windows C partition so that I can get back Windows in the state I had it at the time of the backup.

What I'm thinking is the following:

1) Re-install Bootcamp [Windows 10]

- Going through this process will fix the boot partitions so that I don't have to do it manually

2) Get the vhd file in a format that I can just use a utility to then copy it's contents on to the new C drive

- **Anyone know what I can use to accomplish this ?**

I'd appreciate if someone which some more experience and review and let me know their thoughts on how to do this.

Update 1:

In researching this I'm finding out that I can convert the vhd to raw format and then use dd to copy the raw image to the bootcamp partition in MacOS.

However, the vhd I have is just for the C drive (volume) not the whole bootcamp partition.  So can dd or is there a utility that can copy the C drive (volume) from the raw format that I have to the physical disk C drive (volume) ?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved, more info [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7750942).

Comment: Ordinarily I would copy the text from your link into your answer to save it in case the link gets deleted, but the thread was too complicated for me to copy. If you copy the gist of the link into your answer, I will edit and format it.

Comment: @Exocomp - Please provide the entire and complete solution, within the body of your answer, otherwise it's difficult to determine what exactly from your link was helpful.